# How to resolve CORS issue in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to use Lumo api to accept Bitcoin payment in my ionic app but i am getting this error in the console,

```
  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/funding_address?asset=XBT' 
  from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has 
  been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
  pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
  is present on the requested resource.
```

here is my code

```
userAuthentication() {
        var base64Auth = btoa(`${this.username}:${this.password}`);
        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders(); 
        reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Accept','application/json');      
        reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Authorization','Basic '+base64Auth);
        return this.http.get(this.url,{headers: reqHeader}).subscribe(data=>console.log('data ', data));
  }
```

i also tried this but it didnt work

```
var base64Auth = btoa(`${this.username}:${this.password}`);
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders() 
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic '+base64Auth )
```

pls whats the problem with my code or how can i resolve the cors error

Answer (score 0):

you  follow description
**first step**
you first install npm cors using this command

npm install cors

**step two**
you import cors file in mainfile.js and below a two-line  of code follow

```
const cors=require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

**third step**
using below line code

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: I am using ionic and not nodeJs express, how can i use it in my ionic app

Answer (score -1):

> you can install cors extension in chrome  go below link and try again

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en